# Openlayers Custom build tutorial is crashing

Tags: openlayers-3

I am working through the [openlayers custom build tutorial](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html) and I am getting the following error

```
info ol Parsing dependencies
info ol Compiling 345 sources
events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn java ENOENT
   at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
   (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
   at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
   at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
Exit 1
```

when I run:

```
 node tasks/build.js build/ol-custom.json build/ol-custom.js
```

Googling the error gives a solution where it could be another node instance running in the background (there isnt)

also the tutorial says closure-util should be in:

```
node_modules/openlayers/node_modules
```

but it is actually in:

```
node_modules/closure-util
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out java wasn't set up properly on my path and so it couldn't build. Remember to check your environment with java -version.

On Ubuntu you can install install java 11 (working with this version):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

It should return:

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Then you can run again:

```
 node tasks/build.js build/ol-custom.json build/ol-custom.js
```